# Freelancer Moving from UK to France

Tags: france, relocation, freelance

I am a Freelance copywriter in the UK, relocating to France in a couple of weeks (with a spouse visa that enables me to work). My question is about the transitional period between switching being registered in the UK to France.

I have read online that you are not allowed to work until you receive your SIRET number, but this seems to be advice for brand new businesses. As I have existing client agreements and projects in place, and I'm just moving myself over to France pretty seamlessly, does anyone know if I can continue to invoice them as a UK freelancer for the first few weeks after I arrive until everything is set up?

Frustratingly it seems you can't register your business until you have arrived in France, so I can't do this in advance to limit the changeover time. Thank you so much in advance for any advice!